# Get Model Output while using pytorch lightening

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I am using pytorch lightening for a project. My model outputs word embeddings and I want to save the model outputs in a file. How do I access the model outputs after training is completed ? Should I use callbacks ? While using training_end_epoch(), when I check train_outs, I am only getting outputs of one batch and not outputs of all the batches.

Fyi, I am using pytorch-lightening 0.7.6 due to some code restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are returning the word embeddings from `training_step`. Lets assume you return a dictionary `{'embed': var_embed}`.

You can access the dictionary in `training_epoch_end (self, outputs)`. You can collect outputs from all the batches by using a list. Say,

```
embeds = [x['embed'] for x in outputs]
```

Please post a MWE, it would be easier.